# Como transferir conteúdo de uma variável de um ViewController para outro

Tags: swift, view

Desculpem a minha ignorância de programador iniciante. Segui as dicas acima mas dá um erro quando faço o `self`:

> Cannot assign value of type "TelaPrincipalVieController" to type "TelaAjustesViewController".

`TelaAjustesViewController` é a **Tela 1** do seu exemplo e a `TelaPrincipalViewController` é a **2**.
O valor que vem da **Tela 1**, é o conteúdo de `Cor`.

```
import UIKit

class TelaPrincipalViewController: UIViewController { var TransfereCor:TelaAjustesViewController!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    let v2 = TelaPrincipalViewController ()
    v2.TransfereCor = self
    switch TransfereCor.Cor
    {
    case 0:
        print("Escuro")
        break
    case 1:
        print("Claro")
        break
    case 2:
        print("Daltônico")
        break
    default:
        break
    }
    print(TransfereCor.Cor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vc tem que instanciar a tela anterior:

var TransfereCor:TelaAjustesViewController = TelaAjustesViewController()

Daí sim vc vai poder pegar os atributos dela através de TransfereCor.Cor